# Greek sigma symbol correct representation?

Tags: notation

I wish to display to people that a number is a total. I have decided to use the greek symbol for sum:

```
Σ
```

Do I prefix or suffix numbers with this symbol?

Given the total is 10.

```
Σ10
```

or

```
10Σ
```

Comment: If you really want to use $\Sigma$ for this, maybe $\Sigma=10$.

Comment: Indeed, a mathematician would interpret $\Sigma10$ as adding up some number of tens, and $10\Sigma$ as ten times some sum.

Comment: $\Sigma$ is generally used as an operator.  Thus you might write $\sum_{i=1}^{3} a_i = 10$, which means that the sum of $a_i$ for $i$ from $1$ to $3$, i.e. $a_1 + a_2 + a_3$, is $10$.

Comment: THank you all. I would accept @Andre's comment if it were an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If $S_n$ is some sequence (for $n=a, a+1, a+2, \cdots, b-1, b$), its sum (total), $T$, is:
$$T=\sum_{n=a}^b S_n$$

which is simply another way of saying

$$T=S_a+S_{a+1}+\cdots + S_{b-1}+S_{b}$$

---

Note also that
$$C \sum_{n=a}^b S_n=C(S_a+S_{a+1}+\cdots + S_{b-1}+S_{b})$$

Comment: $S_n$ is a *sequence*; $T$ is (the value of) a *series*.